# Slow load image from button Tool after event Mouse hover and leave in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, performance, button, mousehover

Sorry for my English writing
I am new with VB.Net. I have a button that sets an image background as picture using the Mouse Hover and Mouse Leave to change the image . The Problem is that it seem slow when loading the images after the event. Is there any way to improve the performance?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._1 
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
    Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._2
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not that the image is slow to load but rather the default time it needs to fire the MouseHover Event here is more info on that [mousehovertime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousehovertime.aspx) it seem like it can only be set system wide via a API though.

A alternative would be to use MouseEnter instead of MouseHover

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._1
End Sub
'use a MouseEnter event instead
Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter
    Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._2
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources._1
End Sub
```